# Pass data from activity to fragment ( empty getArguments() )

Tags: android, fragment

I need to pass data from `activity` to `fragment`. 
I did try set `setArguments()` , `broadcast receiver`
and I don't know where I am making a mistake
tip 1: in `MainActivity` `setArguments()` `bundle` is full of stuff but when I call `getArguments()` it's empty, why?

**EDIT  :  i just forgot to load it in MainActivity after intance was saved**

`MainActivity`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        Bundle gameData = getIntent().getExtras();

        float current_zoom =(gameData.getFloat("current_zoom"));
        LatLng current_target =((LatLng)gameData.getParcelable("current_target"));
        float current_bearing =(gameData.getFloat("current_bearing"));
        String current_map_mode = (gameData.getString("current_map_mode"));

        Bundle dataActivityBundle = new Bundle();
        dataActivityBundle.putFloat("current_zoom",current_zoom);
        dataActivityBundle.putParcelable("current_target",current_target);
        dataActivityBundle.putFloat("current_bearing",current_bearing);
        dataActivityBundle.putString("current_map_mode",current_map_mode);

        MapFragment myObj = new MapFragment();
        myObj.setArguments(dataActivityBundle);
        Log.i("Rotate","Arguments : "+String.valueOf(mapFragment.getArguments()));


        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

`MapFragment`:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(mapFragment==null){
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.map,mapFragment).commit();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


       if (getArguments() != null) {

            current_zoom = getArguments().getFloat("current_zoom");
            current_target = getArguments().getParcelable("current_target");
            current_bearing = getArguments().getFloat("current_bearing");
            current_map_mode = getArguments().getString("current_map_mode");

            Log.i("Rotate","onCreateView : getArguments() != null");
            Log.i("Rotate","current_zoom "+getArguments().getFloat("current_zoom"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_target "+getArguments().getParcelable("current_target"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_bearing "+getArguments().getFloat("current_bearing"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_map_mode "+getArguments().getString("current_map_mode"));
        }
}
```

Comment: `MapFragment myObj = new MapFragment();` you are creating a new instance of the Fragment, rather than use the one that's actually being used?

Answer (score 0):

Something you may be doing wrong is performing the fragment transaction in the fragment itself.  Traditionally, the transaction should take place in the parent activity.  Try to refactor your code by moving your transaction logic from `MapFragment` to `MainActivity` like so:

```java
// MainActivity.java
  @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        Bundle gameData = getIntent().getExtras();

        float current_zoom =(gameData.getFloat("current_zoom"));
        LatLng current_target =((LatLng)gameData.getParcelable("current_target"));
        float current_bearing =(gameData.getFloat("current_bearing"));
        String current_map_mode = (gameData.getString("current_map_mode"));

        Bundle dataActivityBundle = new Bundle();
        dataActivityBundle.putFloat("current_zoom",current_zoom);
        dataActivityBundle.putParcelable("current_target",current_target);
        dataActivityBundle.putFloat("current_bearing",current_bearing);
        dataActivityBundle.putString("current_map_mode",current_map_mode);

        // Fragment transaction code moved here
        MapFragment myObj = new MapFragment();
        myObj.setArguments(dataActivityBundle);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.map,mapFragment).commit();
        Log.i("Rotate","Arguments : "+String.valueOf(mapFragment.getArguments()));


        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        // Fragment transaction logic no longer here

        // Call private functions without initializing the object's own class 
        getMapAsync(this);


       if (getArguments() != null) {

            current_zoom = getArguments().getFloat("current_zoom");
            current_target = getArguments().getParcelable("current_target");
            current_bearing = getArguments().getFloat("current_bearing");
            current_map_mode = getArguments().getString("current_map_mode");

            Log.i("Rotate","onCreateView : getArguments() != null");
            Log.i("Rotate","current_zoom "+getArguments().getFloat("current_zoom"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_target "+getArguments().getParcelable("current_target"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_bearing "+getArguments().getFloat("current_bearing"));
            Log.i("Rotate","current_map_mode "+getArguments().getString("current_map_mode"));
        }
}
```